# python scikit-learn extract_patches_2d has strides option?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, patch

I am having problem with making patches from 512x512 images.
I am trying to extract 64x64 patches with stride 32 which is half of the patch wid size.

I found that scikit-learn extract_patches_2d function can extract 2d patches from original image.

When I use this function, it seems the function extract patches stride 1.

Is there any way that I can extract patches stride 32?

```
def load_train_data(self):
    imgs_row, imgs_col = 512,512
    train_list = []
    train_img = []
    label_list = []
    label_img = []
    train_path = 'C:\\Users\\Lee Doyle\\unet\\data\\Train'
    label_path = 'C:\\Users\\Lee Doyle\\unet\\data\\Label'

    ######################Traindata################################

    print('-' * 30)
    print('load train images...')
    print('-' * 30)
    for i in glob.glob(train_path + '/*.[tT][iI][fF]'):
        train_list.append(abspath(i))
    print(len(train_list))
    for i in train_list:
        # print(i)
        img = cv2.imread(i, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        # img=cv2.resize(img,(512,512))
        
        #train_img = image.extract_patches_2d(img, (64,64))
               
        train_img.append(img.astype(np.float32)/255.0)
        #train_img.append(img.astype(np.float32)/255.0)
    
    train_img = image.extract_patches_2d(img, (64,64))
   
    train_img = np.array(train_img[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The extract_patches_2d has no stride argument (maybe you can add as a feature request to their github).

I see two possible ways of fixing that, you either write your own function (which is very simple) or you can select the patches you want after using the function.

I would go for the first.